# How to set images to RatingBar which come from web?

Tags: android, image, ratingbar

In my project I have one service which returns image of Ratting, i want to set this image to RattingBar. Does anybody know how to set image dynamically in RattingBar ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply this:

```
ratingbar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rating_bar_selector));
```

rating_bar_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/your_image" />
  <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"  
                   android:drawable="@drawable/your_image_half selected" />
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress"  
                 android:drawable="@drawable/your_image_full_selected" />
</layer-list>
```